# OSM - Iterate over all pixel

Tags: java, loops, pixel, openstreetmap

I'm new in working with OpenStreetMaps.

i want to iterate to every pixel from OpenStreetMap and get the colour of this (RGB). I have implemented the Maps in HTML and JavaFX. Can I do this directly in OSM or did I need a jpg oder png?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

OSM [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) are usually PNG or rarely JPEG.